# Render label with percentage, name of category and an arrow

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I would like to generate a pie chart using jqplot. My code is the following http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/dFgGj/

As you can see, labels are activated but, when the percentage is too low, label can not be rendered.

My goal is to have something like that, with label linked to the pie by a little stroke: http://www.statmethods.net/graphs/images/pie2.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two parts to your question:

1.) How to move the labels to the outside of their wedge?

jqPlot has an option for this: `dataLabelPositionFactor`

```
   rendererOptions: {
        showDataLabels: true,
        dataLabels: myLabels,
        dataLabelPositionFactor: 1.2,
        sliceMargin: 4,
        fill: false
    }
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dFgGj/7/).

2.) How do I draw a little arrow from wedge to moved label?

I see no built in way to do this.  You could draw it yourself in the canvas.  If I can find some time tonight/tomorrow, I'll be back.

Answer (score 0):

```
rendererOptions: {
            showDataLabels: true,
            dataLabelThreshold:1,
            dataLabelPositionFactor: 1.1
        }
```

the option "dataLabelThreshold" default is 3

fiddle [click here](http://jsfiddle.net/renwolang521/uawus/2/)